# Excel VBA: cannot Sum() over Range()

Tags: excel, vba

How should I fix this code because it throws: "The object doesn't support this property or method"

```
Sub macro1()
    Workbooks("OUTPUT.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("B4") = _ 
    Workbooks("INPUT.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Sum(Range("D40:D50"))
End Sub
```

Above code works fine when adjusted as:

```
Sub macro2()
    Workbooks("OUTPUT.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("B4") = _
    Workbooks("INPUT.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D40")
End Sub
```

However it's not acceptable solution because I want to Sum() over Range() as described in macro1().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WorkSheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224506%28v=office.11%29.aspx) doesn't have a sum function, try using [WorksheetFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224507%28v=office.11%29.aspx) instead:

```
Sub macro1() 
    Workbooks("OUTPUT.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("B4") = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Workbooks("INPUT.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D40:D50"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

try

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("D40:D50"))
```